# OBD2 steering angle PID

Tags: obd-ii, steering

I'm trying to get the steering angle of my car via the OBD2 port. I'm using a usb adapter, and Pyserial to read from it.

I found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs

Which lists the PIDs available. It works for the speed etc but I can't find the steering wheel angle (which is supposed to be available through OBD2).

Any idea on how to get it ?

My car is a Renault Espace IV

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the make and model of your car. Cars don't use all possible OBD codes, so yours may not send it...

Comment: @RoryAlsop I've edited it

Comment: Make sure you're pulling PIDs from the ESC module or sometimes the ABS module.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard PID for the steering angle defined in the official standard. You need to consult manufacturer specific documentation for your vehicle to find out whether there is a PID available for that. Chances are you can't get it via a PID but need to resort to lower level CAN commands.